# lambda handler for multiple triggers in aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch-events

How will the Lambda handler of `multiple different types of trigger` look like in java?
I want to set a trigger for `Cloudwatch Event Rule`, `S3`. How can I do this?

```
public class App implements RequestHandler<S3Event, Context>
{
public Context handleRequest(S3Event s3event, Context context) {
     System.out.println("welcome to lambda");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean a single lambda will be triggered by multiple different types of trigger (S3Event and ScheduledEvent, for example) ?

Comment: @mattfreake Yes

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: The stream solution below definitely works, but lambdas are meant to be small units of code, so it can be a red flag that your lambda is trying to do too much. You are also limiting your ability to manage the processing of the types of event differently, if you only have one lambda whose concurrency etc you can modify

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Map<String,String>` as input

```java
public class Handler implements RequestHandler<Map<String,String>, String>{
  @Override
  public String handleRequest(Map<String,String> event, Context context) {
  }
}
```

Or use `RequestStreamHandler` and parse the InputStream to the correct object.

```java
public class HandlerStream implements RequestStreamHandler {
  @Override
  public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) throws IOException {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using a generic `Object` could work, I use Serverless Framework with:

```java
package com.serverless;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class Handler implements RequestHandler<Object, Object> {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(Handler.class);

    @Override
    public Object handleRequest(final Object input, final Context context) {
        LOG.info("received: {}", input);
        return input;
    }
}
```